# Deploying Lightning Email Templates via Metadata API

Tags: email-template, metadata-api, deployment-error

I am getting this error when attempting to deploy my Lightning Email Template:
**You don't have the right to create Lightning pages of type EmailTemplatePage.**

In my deployment I have the .email file and the .flexipage file. In my target org I have the permission for drag-and-drop email builder and I have the Lightning Email templates enabled. Any idea?

According to SF documentation(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm) this is not retrievable or deployable. But i was able to retrieve still, so hoping I can find a way to deploy too.

Comment: Do you have "Manage Public Lightning Email Template" permission enabled on profile?

Comment: Yes I do have that permission assigned to my user in the target and source orgs. @Vinay